# Use of ... all are?

Tags: meaning, syntactic-analysis, word-order, quantifiers

Is the *all* in "John, Bob, and Sue all are hungry" redundant? Does it mean anything beyond "John, Bob, and Sue are hungry"?

Comment: The "all" here is separable and not part of the subject NP but a quantificational adjunct in clause structure, thus it's optional.

Comment: Your sentence is not (well-formed) English. If you wish to  include “all” it is better to follow the verb, i.e. “are all”.

Comment: _All_ is one of the quantifiers that allow [Quantifier-Float](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299+Quantifier+Float), so that _John, Bob, and Sue all are hungry_ is one variant, and _John, Bob, and Sue are all hungry_ is another, of _All of John, Bob, and Sue are hungry._ Even though the quantifier modifies the noun phrase, you can see how useful it is to niche it in the verb phrase.

Comment: @JohnLawler Even _John, Bob and Sue are hungry all_ is possible, though old-fashioned, if not archaic.

Comment: Is there a term that describes a usage that, while apparently in some sense technically possible, sounds so obviously wrong (but close to right) to my ears that if I heard it, my brain would automatically treat it as a mistake and correct it without my noticing?  If so, this falls into that category for me (at least in the US).

Comment: @David Your comment (the first sentence) and the one following can't both be right.

Comment: @cruthers 'infelicitous'. In linguistics, they use '*' to mark a sentence for 'wrong grammar' = 'this is never said in this variety', and '?' for 'this sounds weird but maybe it's OK...maybe?'. I don't know if 'infelicitous' is used technically. I don't think there is a term for 'mostly ungrammatical with usual prosody, but if you have a very particular context in mind and pause and emphasize the right way it totally becomes grammatical, but that situation is rare'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth — Could be I'm wrong, better, to have stuck to "better". I still think "are all" is more natural than "all are" in the particular example.

Comment: It's what I'd use too, but Lawler is an accepted authority on the English Language.

Answer (score 1):

> *John, Bob, and Sue all are hungry.*

The "all" is separable and not part of the subject NP but an adjunct in clause structure. This is evident from the fact that when the verb is an auxiliary, as it is here, it preferentially follows rather than precedes it, as in "John, Bob and Sue" are all hungry".

Note also the possibility of inserting an adjunct after the subject NP and before the quantificational adjunct, as in "John, Bob and Sue are certainly all hungry".